# Finding documentation on how to import JSON from URL in Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4

I did my research and found a [working example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY3bTxgxWss&t=29s), 
but I could not find any documentation that explicitly explains importing JSON from URL and decoding it. Perhaps, I am searching with wrong keywords.

So, **what keywords should use** to find out how to import JSON from URL in Swift 4? Are there any well-documented blog post or documentations for it?

I went to the [Apple's official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) on JSON decoding and it says...

```
import Foundation

let data: Data // received from a network request, for example
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
```

This is not helpful at all!
I realized a lot of tutorials skip this step to fetch JSON from URL or just locally create a JSON object. like [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder) [this](https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/) [this](https://roadfiresoftware.com/2018/02/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-4/)

Please help me find a good source for this.

Comment: how to import JSON from URL in Swift 4 , why not Codable ?

Comment: There's nothing specific about loading JSON from a URL. It's just data. There are countless examples of using URLSession.

Comment: While the duplicate is title "in Swift 3", it's still the same thing since your question is about getting the JSON, not parsing it. Of course in Swift 4 you generally using Decodable and not JSONSerialization but there are countless examples of that too.

Comment: @rmaddy Okay ill take a look at the duplicate answer. And also I guess you mean I need to look up `URLSession`?